# Returning a zend paginator object in ajax request, getting wrong url

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework, zend-paginator

I'm using [Zend Paginator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.advanced.html) here, in an ajax request I am retrieving objects based upon search results and rendering the HTML and passing it along with a rendered Zend Paginator view.

The problem is that the returning paginator doesn't take into account the new url. for example if I were to do it without ajax I would have my page url read:

www.mysite.com/?search=something&page=2

However from and ajax query it doesn't work that way the search variable is not appended to the url in the paginator links. Help please.

Comment: Can we see the code you are working on. Zend Paginator does not have any issues with rendering page url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you hava **pagination links** somewhere on your site that point to the different pages that are generated within you **pagination.phtml** file.

OnClick you need to get that **href attribute** and load the contents like that:

```
function getContents() {
    var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + 
              window.location.host + $(this).attr('href');

    var jqxhr = $.post(url, {
        "format" : "json"
    }, function(data) {
        displayContents(data);
    }, 'html');
    return false;
} 

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#paginator a").each(function() {
        $(this).click(getContents);
    });
});
```

This way you get your classic url

```
www.mysite.com/?search=something&page=2
```

maybe you need to change the url field. Just alert the url field and look what needs to be changed.

Here is a tutorial on that (without search) : [Zend Framework 1.9 tutorial 14: ajax requests part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xrw8TP62-XU&playnext=1&list=PLC7FDFC7E0F370A02)

Comment: Actually my question wasn't in regards to ajax paginator but to teh HTML built by the Zend Paginator object. It appears that the zend paginator takes the current URL as the base to build the links. However in an ajax query the current URL may not necessarily be the actual url that needs to be built here.

Comment: I am not sure where your problem is. In your question you say the ajax part doesn't work. Does the non-ajax pagination work so far?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code I can't be sure, but it sounds like your Paginator Controls View Scripts (i.e. the `.phtml` files which render your Next, Previous, etc links) is using the `$this->url()` but you haven't configured it to detect and append the search parameter onto the end of the links.

If your control view scripts are specific for that Paginator, try manually adding the "?search=something" in your `<a>` tag's href parameter. This should force it to include these in the output.

It would be great if you could provide us with the code from your Controller and View showing how you are implementing the Paginator and rendering the pages. Or a live Demo is always good :D